# Integral with variable limits in python

Tags: python, variables, scipy, integral, quad

I'm trying to compute the following integral

[image]

using scipy, with the following program:

```
def E(z):
    result = 1/np.sqrt(Om*(1 + z)**3 + Ode + Ox*(1 + z)**2)
    return result 

def r(z, E): 
    result, error  = quad(E, 0, z) # integrate E(z) from 0 to z
    return result
```

z being the independent variable, while Om Ode and Ox are simply constants (previously assigned).
When I then try to call the function:

```
z = np.linspace(1e-3, 4, 300)
plt.plot(z, r(z))
```

I get the error

```
flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() 
or a.all()
```

What is the problem? Is scipy.quad unable to integrate up to a variable?
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Can you include sample values for your contants?

Comment: You are feeding a `numpy` array to [`scipy.integrate.quad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html), but it only accepts `float`.

Comment: Om  = 0.32
Ode = 0.68
Ox  = 0

Comment: That's right! So how could I pass a float to quad but still obtain a function and not just a number?

Comment: You can do something like this `vals = [r(zi,E) for zi in z]` (not sure if this is the most efficient way though)

Comment: Lools like it's working! Thank you much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of Python's [`map(function, iterable, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map) function,

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

and `functools` [`partial(func[,*args][, **keywords])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) method:

> Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments keywords.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial


def E(z):
    Om = 0.32
    Ode = 0.68
    Ox = 0
    result = 1/np.sqrt(Om*(1 + z)**3 + Ode + Ox*(1 + z)**2)

    return result


def r(z):
    result = np.array(
        list(map(partial(quad, E, 0), z))
    )[:, 0]  # integrate E(z) from 0 to z

    return result


z = np.linspace(1e-3, 4, 300)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(z, r(z))
fig.show()
```

[image]